# How to get different terminals for dual monitor scheme without X

Tags: linux, terminal, tty, multiple-monitors

I have Ubuntu installed without X.org with two monitors(single card: vga and dvi)
Login shell is cloned for both monitors. 
I there any way to have different shells(tty) for these monitors?

Answer (score 1):

It [seems possible](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Framebuffer-HOWTO/x1010.html) - the insturctions are a bit dated, but given that framebuffer console support has been in kernel for ages, and there is a [framebuffer terminal emulator](http://code.google.com/p/fbterm/), you probably can achieve this.